# Windows Form UserControl design time properties

Tags: c#, design-time

I am struggling with a UserControl. I have a UserControl that represent a Pager and it has a Presenter object property exposed in this way:

```
[Browsable(false)]
[DesignSerializationAttribute(DesignSerializationAttribute.Hidden)]    
public object Presenter { get; set; }
```

The code itself works as I can drag and drop a control into a Windows From without having Visual Studio initializing this property.
Now, because in the Load event of this control I call a method of the Presenter that at run-time is null ... I have introduced this additional code:

```
public override void OnLoad(...)
{
   if (this.DesignMode)
   {
      base.OnLoad(e);
      return;
   }
   presenter.OnViewReady();
}
```

Now, every time I open a Window that contains this UserControl, Visual Studio modifies the Windows designer code. So, as soon as I open it, VS ask me if I want to save it ... and of course, if I add a control to the Window, it doesn't keep the changes ... As soon as I remove the UserControl Pager the problem disappears ...
How should I tackle that in the proper way? I just don't want that the presenter property is initialized at design time as it is injected at runtime ...

Comment: Are you aware that you are not invoking `base.OnLoad` if you are not in design mode? Is this intentional?

Comment: What changes in the designer file?

Comment: yeah, don't worry, the code is calling base.OnLoad(e) also if not at design-time, I skipped here to show you that the presenter is called only at run-time but the issue is different ...

Comment: nothing really changes, but the changes I do are blow away when I save ...

Comment: The 2nd attribute on the property is nonsense.  Do make sure to copy/paste from your source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the exception is thrown by the Designer of the Windows form that contains the UserControl:

Instances of this error (1)

1. Infrastructure.BaseModule.MYWindow.Designer.cs Line:108 Column:1   Hide Call Stack

at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.Error(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String exceptionText, String helpLink)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)

Comment: I found the error:
I named the control Library...PagerView.PagerView where the PagerView is both, the namespace and the name of the Control. In VS Designer this can't be done because it will try to resolve the namespace istead of the control name.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting an exception when VS tries to generate the designer code.

Attach a second copy of VS to the designer, turn on Break On Exceptions, and see what's going on.

Comment: So the problem is just with that attribute ... If I remove it everything is fine except that VS initialize the Presenter proeprty and I don't want that ...

Comment: So the exception is thrown by the Designer of the Windows form that contains the UserControl: